# Calling a C# DLL from C# using GetProcAddress

Tags: c#, dll

My program needs to call methods from a C# dll file that is specified in runtime.
In order to do that, I thought of using GetProcAddess like this:

```
string sytDll = @"C:\Programming\dllexample.dll";
IntPtr DllLoaded = LoadLibrary(sytDll);
if (DllLoaded != IntPtr.Zero)
{
   IntPtr pSytCheck = GetProcAddress(DllLoaded, "f1");  
}
```

Dlloaded returns a value, however GetProcAddress always returns 0.

I'm wondering if the C# DLL has the right format. This is how it looks:

```
namespace dllexample
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static int f1(int a)
        {
            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

I have the impression I'm not declaring dll correctly, or I'm not using the right function name.

Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `GetProcAddress` is going to work for C or C++ exported functions. For .Net, you instead need to load the assembly and use reflection (I think).

Comment: This will not work. In C# such problems are solved by this way: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/546639/How-to-create-an-easy-plugin-system-in-Csharp

Answer (score 0):

The DLL is entirely appropriate and not the problem. The problem is that I don't know why you are calling the method from the DLL via GetProcAddress() and not simply importing the DLL into your program and calling the function from its pure class. That is, you should do:

- Remove what you have from GetProcAddress()
- Add a library DLL to the program from which you want to call the DLL method
- Use it by `using Your_dll_name;`
- Create a quick class selector e.g. DLLClass dllclass = new DLLClass();
- And call the method using dllclass.